iOS Widget sometimes does not show images (ERROR: could not find plugin for image source )
I'm building my first iOS app with SwiftUI and trying to show images in a Widget. That works most of the time, but sometimes, images won't render, even if it already worked to show them in the past. It seems to be completely arbitrary. I would say that it works in 95% of the time, but fails in 5% of all cases (I refresh the widget once per hour).
Now I've collected some logs, but I can't find something useful about the errors:
standard    06:39:45.111861+0200    WidgetsExtension    container_create_or_lookup_app_group_path_by_app_group_identifier: success
fehler  06:39:45.124706+0200    WidgetsExtension    CreateWithURL:342: *** ERROR: err=1 (Operation not permitted) - could not open '<CFURL 0x102346d60 [0x1f78674f8]>{string = file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/DBD07167-ED05-4BDF-A302-5173C84F0717/5230A437-503C-430E-A808-4AEF47D4D1B9-systemSmall.jpg, encoding = 134217984, base = (null)}'
fehler  06:39:45.126538+0200    WidgetsExtension    createImageAtIndex:1869: *** ERROR: could not find plugin for image source - imageRead is NULL
fehler  06:39:45.126574+0200    WidgetsExtension    createImageAtIndex:2007: *** ERROR: createImageAtIndex[0] - 'n/a ' - failed to create image [-62]
fehler  06:39:45.126601+0200    WidgetsExtension    CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex:4984: *** ERROR: CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex[0] - 'n/a ' - failed to create image [-62]

This is how I try to load the image (source code also available here):
struct HighlightsTile: View {
    var highlight: Moment
    var photoImage: UIImage?

    init(highlights: [Moment], size: ImageSize) {
        self.highlight = highlights[0]

        if highlight.photo != nil {
            let photoUrl = FileManager.documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(String(describing: highlight.photo!))-\(size).jpg")
            self.photoImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: photoUrl.path)
        }
    }
}

Update 1
I don't think I've explained it well enough: the error occurs sometimes for an image which never had problems to load before. That's why I think it could be related to threading, race conditions, concurrently file access, ... first time I build a Swift app, so I don't know if some of this thoughts could be a real problem.
Update 2
I found a way to reproduce the problem. I've set the passcode to "Immediately" and now loading of images in the widget doesn't work anymore. So if the iPhone is locked, loading images in the background does not work. Any idea how to "allow" this? –

"Sometimes" is usually indicative of assuming that widgets "listen" your widgets should only have let properties, all the data should come from the getTimeline method. if you are doing asynchronous work or expecting other things like property wrappers to work you widget will fail. It will work sometimes because the update is fast enough but if there is any delay it will fail. View a Widget like a GIF

Ha! I found a way to reproduce the problem. I've set the passcode to "Immediately" and now loading of images in the widget doesn't work anymore. So if the iPhone is locked, loading images in the background does not work. Any idea how to "allow" this?

I haven’t looked at your code there is no way for me to know. I don’t look at links on SO. Most of us answer questions for everyone to learn from them, it is a community thing, your links only help you because they aren’t searchable.

Understandable, but I meant if you are aware of such a restriction, not if you found the problem in my code :)

A lot of things are restricted by passcode. It is the whole encryption thing. Apple protects sensitive data/areas from use when the devices are locked.

But I can‘t find any documentation about this. I have an app group container where the app stores images and the widget reads the files from. It‘s not mentioned anywhere that this does not work when the device is locked, so I have no clue how to deal with it.

https://support.apple.com/guide/security/app-protection-and-app-groups-sec1a976c067/web

Aaah, I think that's the problem: "User-installed apps that don’t opt in to a specific Data Protection class receive Protected Until First User Authentication by default.". Thanks!

Anytime! Glad to help.

Ok, I think it's not the problem ... this protection level is described as follows: "After the user unlocks the device for the first time, your app can access the file and continue to access it even if the user subsequently locks the device". Since I don't have another protection level set, the images should be accessible, even if my phone is locked. Damn.

It is probably a timing issues it almost always is when “sometimes” is in play with widgets. Make all your properties “let” in the widget and make sure you are using async/await properly

Ok, I'll have a look, thanks!

Just a wild guess: I remember some odd issues when Widget is using large images, try to limit it to 150 150 before saving it (in the main app)
func resizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        let size = image.size

        let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / size.width
        let heightRatio = targetSize.height / size.height

        // Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
        var newSize: CGSize
        if widthRatio > heightRatio {
            newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio)
        } else {
            newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio, height: size.height * widthRatio)
        }

        // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize)

        // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
        image.draw(in: rect)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage
    }

usage
let imageData = try Data(contentsOf: url)
let uiImage = UIImage(data: imageData)!
let resizedImage = resizeImage(image: uiImage, targetSize: CGSize(width: 150, height: 150))
try? resizedImage?.pngData()?.write(to: destination)


I'm already resizing the image before I save it :-(

I see that the first error you receive is related to the file not opening. One code smell I found would may be the use of String(describing: highlight.photo)

Use this initializer to convert an instance of any type to its preferred representation as a String instance.

Does your highlight.photo conform to CustomStringConvertible?
You should use .appendingPathComponent() and provide the exact file name, and not 'describe' it

The image exists, it works in most of the cases, but just in some cases not. So the way I build the filename should be ok I think?

Verify that the image is being loaded correctly from the file path. You can add a debug print statement to check the path and ensure the image exists.

The image exists, it works in most of the cases, but just in some cases not.

For which cases its not working, is it frequent? or time being?

Can you try below and print imageName and check what it comes for failure case
let imageName = "\(highlight.photo ?? "")-\(size).jpg"
let photoUrl = FileManager.documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(imageName)
print("imageName==\(imageName)")
print("photoUrl==\(photoUrl)")

Second issue I am guessing is image size is big in-terms of MB and/OR pixels. Try with smaller size images & check once.

Thanks, I'll do this. I create thumbnails for widgets with the exact widget size. Images are around 200kb, so they shouldn't be too big in terms of file size or resolution.

@Slevin : Any luck?

Unfortunately not :-(

@Slevin : delete apps and restart devices and try... else need to look into it more detailed way...

A wild guess:
You are trying to access photoImage from the documentsDirectory.
Could it be that your iOS target can read it successfully, while your widget target cannot?
If this is the case, this is expected behavior, because both targets are isolated from each other.
If both targets have to use the same file, it has to be stored in an App Group.
An App Group allows access to group containers that are shared among multiple related apps, and allows certain additional interprocess communication between the apps.

But then access in general wouldn't work. The widget shows the image successfully in most of the cases. But in some rare cases it doesn't. The same image that has worked fine before.

Hmmm... I don't understand how your iOS target and your widget target can access the same file in the document directory without using an App Group. But if this is the case, I don't have another idea, sorry.

I'm already using an app group for this :-)
